# Is OpenId Connect too complex for this scenario?

Tags: openid-connect

I want to implement authentication in a website and the corresponding API for an app to consume.

I was thinking of deploying a local OpenId Connect server to handle authentication related tasks. However, I am told that the main feature of OpenId Connect is delegation, which I am not interested in. Right now I do not need to delegate any task to third parties.

I am thinking that I may not need the complexity of OpenId Connect for my needs. What do you think? Is there any simpler solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main feature of OAuth 2.0 is delegation, the main feature of OpenID Connect (which is built on top of OAuth 2.0) is authentication.

OpenID Connect is not complex and very well suited for your task: it can deliver both an `id_token` that authenticates the user as well as an `access_token` that your app can use to consume an API in a single flow.

There is really not a (much) simpler solution and certainly not one that is standardized.